# Matplotlib stacked bar chart not showing all bars

Tags: matplotlib, stacked-chart

I will make a stacked bar chart in matplotlib. Somehow it doesnt include all the bar chart that i gave him (there should be like 50 bar charts stacked on each other)

The code:

```
N=45 #numbers of columns
max_el=50
ind=np.arrange(N)
for bar in range(0,max_el):
   y=[dic[value][bar] for value in dic]
   plt.bar(ind,y,)
plt.show()
```

note: I used the similar code and same data and made a stacked bar chart with plotly (which worked)

With plotly
[image: how it should look like]

With matplotlib
[image: how it looks like]

Some of the values of variables are zeros or 0.1. Could that be the problem ?

Comment: You are not stacking the bars. Refer to the [stacked bar graph example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html) on how to create stacked bars.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest what am i doing wrong ? I cant type all the data maunally, i need to use dics and loops

Comment: oh i got it.... 
with plotly was so much nicer. Now i have to calculate for each graph the "bottom"

Answer (score 1):

As described in the comments, you need to add a bottoms array that keeps track of how much each should be moved up from the 0 line.  Otherwise, they all start plotting a 0 and overplot one another, with the tallest one sticking up to its values and each one hiding those that were plotted before.